# Why would a foreign military aircraft be parked at a US Air Force base?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, eurofighter-typhoon

The aircraft in the attached Google Earth screenshot appears to be a Eurofighter Typhoon, parked all alone on the tarmac at Eglin AFB, Florida.  Why would one single foreign fighter like this be found on a US military base?  Granted, the Typhoon is mostly operated by US allies, but it still seems strange.

Also, can anyone identify the livery/operator of the aircraft in question?

[image: fighter aircraft on the tarmac at Eglin AFB (image from Google)]

Comment: As to the operator, it's tough to tell from the low resolution but my guess would be the UK (spanish jets appear to have roundels on both wings, german jets have the cross instead, italians have a red circle roundel, Oman does not appear to put them on either wing, and as seen in [this](https://i0.wp.com/theaviationist.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/RSAF-Typhoon.jpg?fit=1200%2C743&ssl=1) picture, Saudi typhoons have a more subdued roundel and "RSAF" on the right wing). UK jets feature a blue outer circle on their roundel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actually fairly common for NATO aircraft to be at Eglin AFB.  When I was stationed there (a long time ago) we had two RAF Tornadoes on site for several months.

Eglin AFB is the home to the munitions development programs. Part of that development includes ensuring the weapons are compatible with the aircraft that will deploy them. Eglin also has a large test range to support that effort.

Since we sell the majority of our munitions throughout NATO (common weapons reduce the  size of stockpiles and increase flexibility), they also need to be tested on NATO aircraft. The Eurofighter is likely there for testing.

Comment: It's also very common for NATO (or even non-NATO US allies, like Israeli) military aircraft to be parked at USAF bases during joint exercises such as Red Flag. These are rarely if not never at Eglin, but I don't think OP's question is location-based. So with that said, the premise of the question is very normal, "there's nothing to see here" kind of normal :)